# why is for loop true on equal

Tags: php, for-loop

My for loop is true when variables are equal.
Why is that when i'm only using "smaller than"?

I have a while loop that prints dates from mysql.
$today_nr is a day nr stored in db. ex: 02

Now i´d like a for loop to print out dates that is missing.
ex: 01, 02, 03. If first reccord in mysql is 04.

So i use this for loop. But it will echo both "01" from mysql($today_nr) and "1" from $i

**PHP**

```
$today_nr = $date->format('d');
$i = 1;

for(;$i < $today_nr; $i++){
  echo $i;
}
```

**FULL SCRIPT**

https://eval.in/367692
Line 532

**The Print** for loop is printing 1 after while loop printed 01.

01 Ons  04:41   13:10   0.50    7.97    -0.03       1.32    
1
02 Tor  04:40   13:18   0.50    8.13        0.13    1.33    
2
3
4
5
6
07 Tis  04:41   12:58   0.50    7.77    -0.23       1.32    
7
08 Ons  04:43   13:08   0.50    7.92    -0.08       1.28

Comment: Not clear enough. Add some example values properly.

Comment: [Can't reproduce it](https://eval.in/367667) Please make sure your show us your **full** and **real** code. Also add your current output and your expected output

Comment: @Rizier123 This code is pretty large. I will try to add more info.

Comment: problem is that you are not getting today's date. you just write $date->format('d'); but you not initialize date any where.

Comment: Can you show what is in the `$date` variable?

Comment: $hdvianna $date changes in a while loop from saved dates in a month. So like 01-31.

Comment: @Rizier123 Check link to full script..

Comment: @sgtBOSE Full script in link...

Comment: Lines 89/90 where `$date` is initialised - what's in `$row['usr_stamp_in'];`?  Is it possible it's not the 20th?

Comment: @JamesThorpe $row['usr_stamp_in'] is datetime. diffrent dates as the while loop goes threw this month. so for ex: "2015-05-10 05:30:00" next round can be: "2015-05-14 05:25:00" The problem i have is that i got my for loop dates out on the 14th and 10th. In this case i´d like only the stored dates to print...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

**PHP**

```
//Loop out dates missing in db
//If $i is bigger than today nr
if($i > $today_nr){
   $i = $today_nr;
}

//Loop out missing days
for(;$today_nr != $i;){

  //Set data about day
  $iDate = $year."-".$selected_month."-".$i;
  $iDate = new DateTime($iDate);
  $iDay = $iDate->format('D');

  //Translate iDay. Eng - Swe
  include('../../../include/translate_days_iDay.php');

  //Echo out table
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='print_table_text'>".$iDate->format('W')."</td>";
  echo "<td class='print_table_text'>".$iDate->format('d')." ".$iDay."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  //Add to i
  $i++;
  //if i is bigger than a month
  if($i > $days_in_month){
    break;
  }
}
//If today and i is equal
if($today_nr == $i){
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't like what you are saying in my case the code below works perfect with not an issue as you provided and
**It works as you expects:**

```
<?php
$today_date = date('d', time());
// $today_nr = $date->format('d');
$i = 1;

for(;$i < $today_date; $i++){
  echo $i; // result: 12345678910111213141516171819
}
```